# Load Pandas DF to Big Query fails

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

Im using to following code (Based on example  [pandas-gbq-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013943/google-cloud-bigquery-load-table-from-dataframe-parquet-attributeerror)) 
as following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "link_to_credentials.json"

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'my_string': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'my_int64': [1, 2, 3],
        'my_float64': [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
    }
)
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset('TMP')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('yosh_try_uload_from_client')

client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_ref).result()
```

And Im getting the following error:

```
ImportError: Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'.
pyarrow or fastparquet is required for parquet support
```

After Looking at some SO questions like this one:

[google-cloud-bigquery-load-table-from-dataframe-parquet-attributeerror : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013943/google-cloud-bigquery-load-table-from-dataframe-parquet-attributeerror)

I understand that I need to change something in the configuration (Maybe add a schema?)

Can some one help me out here, i didn't manage to understand from the docs how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install `pyarrow` ([docs](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_dataframe.html) indicate that, unless you have a parquet engine, an `ImportError` will be raised). The [`load_table_from_dataframe`](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/client.html#Client.load_table_from_dataframe) method writes the dataframe to parquet and sets source format to parquet in the load job. I am not really sure why this choice is made but it's hard-coded and installing `pyarrow` is more straightforward and safer than making your own implementation using a different format.

Comment: Thanks, that import moved me to the other bug:  "Provided Schema does not match Table .... '''. Cannot add fields :(

Comment: That indicates that `yosh_try_uload_from_client` has a different schema than what you are indicating with your dataframe. You can pass to `load_table_from_dataframe` a `job_config` including a schema and a `write_disposition` of `WRITE_TRUNCATE` (default is `WRITE_APPEND`). Check [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html) for more.

Comment: Yep, you are right again, i fixed that as well, thanks!